# Unpacking many columns of lists using apply get ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I want to unpack multiple columns of lists into many more columns. Basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns) but **for multiple columns** of lists rather than just one, and avoiding for loops.

As an example I have a `pandas.DataFrame`,

```
import pandas as pd

tst = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 2]]* 5, 'B': [[3, 4]]* 5, 'C': [[5, 6]] * 5})
```

I can easily unpack one of the columns e.g. `A` into multiple columns,

```
pd.DataFrame(tst['A'].to_list(), 
             columns=['1' + tst['A'].name, '2' + tst['A'].name],
             index=list(range(tst['A'].shape[0]))
            )
```

However when I tried expanding this to multiple columns using `.apply` to avoid a for loop,

```
tst.apply(
    lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.to_list(), 
                           columns=['1' + x.name, '2' + x.name], 
                           index=list(range(x.shape[0]))
                          )
)
```

I get the below error, however I am supplying an `index`...

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Is there a way to fix this so that I get an output as per below? (column order doesn't matter)

```
    1C  2C  1B  2B  1A  2A
0   5   6   3   4   1   2
1   5   6   3   4   1   2
2   5   6   3   4   1   2
3   5   6   3   4   1   2
4   5   6   3   4   1   2
```

`pd.__version__ == '1.0.5'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can horizontally `stack` the columns, then create a new dataframe and rename the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(tst.values.T.tolist()))
df.columns = [f'{i}{c}' for c in tst for i in range(1,3)]
```

Alternatively you can `concat` along `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(tst[c].tolist()) for c in tst], axis=1)
df.columns = [f'{i}{c}' for c in tst for i in range(1,3)]
```

---

```
print(df)

   1A  2A  1B  2B  1C  2C
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   1   2   3   4   5   6
3   1   2   3   4   5   6
4   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great - I accepted this as the answer as the performance as a lot better for my actual `df` which had many columns / rows of lists

Comment: @RK1 happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to change `apply`to `explode` then this is one line solution. Kr.

```
res=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(tst[[x]].explode(x).values.reshape(-1,2), columns=['1' + x, '2' + x]) for x in tst.columns], 1)
print(res)
```

Which returns:

```
  1A 2A 1B 2B 1C 2C
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  1  2  3  4  5  6
3  1  2  3  4  5  6
4  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked well (a bit slow) but it seemed to work with `NoneTypes` which is pretty useful